# Using jQuery UI Menu on hover not working for submenu

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, menu, submenu

I am using jQuery UI Menu plugin in my app. I got one issue.

In sub-menu (2nd level) If I hover mouse repetitively on single Sub menu item then sometime Hover action not happened.

```
ITEM 1

ITEM 2

ITEM 3 -> ITEM 3-1 

          ITEM 3-2     


ITEM 4

ITEM 5
```

Explaining the scenario here :

I copied demo example from here http://api.jqueryui.com/menu/#entry-examples  and added one more sub menu level under Item 3-2 .
Now hover the mouse on Item 3-2 next level come up but If I do hover repetitively then at certain point on hover the next level not came up.

To reproduce this issue follow this steps

1. Mouse over on Item 3 – this displays Menu
2. Mouse over on Item 3-2  – Sub menu appears
3. Mouse out from the sub menu – But, don’t click outside of the menu, so that Item 3 menu still open.
4. Now Mouse over on Item 3-2 (select the same item selected in step – 2 , Do repetitively on this menu item and check) – Sub menu is not coming.

Comment: show http://jsfiddle.net/ of your example

Comment: updated jsfiddle link here .. Please check the example  http://jsfiddle.net/gokul2287/qy332/

Comment: @rjdmello: Same thing happen here too.. try to reproduce above issue. mouse hover on item 3-2 repetitively .. at certain point hover not happen

Comment: Hello 

The issue exist in jQuery UI Menu and for to resolve this ticket has raised. 

please check here.

https://forum.jquery.com/topic/problem-in-jquery-ui-menu-on-hover

Answer (score 2):

The mouseleave event bound to the root menu should run collapseAll( event, true ), not just be bound directly to collapseAll(), eg.

@ line 102 of jquery.ui.menu.js

```
            mouseleave: "collapseAll",
            mouseleave: function( event ){
                this.collapseAll( event, true );
            },
```

Comment: tried but not working same issue again. did not understand the root cause